# Resolving git pull merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, pull

Is it correct that for git pull (and thus git merge by extension) to throw merge conflicts, the local and remote repositories have to be out of sync ? Basically, is it necessary for these 2 conditions to be met in order to get a merge conflict -

- There must be at least one commit made locally that hasn't been pushed to remote.
- There must be at least one commit made on remote (that hasn't been pulled yet) that involves the changing the same line of code as one of the commits made locally (that hasn't been pushed yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much correct.

As for the merge: Certainly there must be a commit on your side that the remote doesn't have; otherwise we'd fast forward, which is not really a merge. And there must be a commit on the remote that you don't have: otherwise nothing would happen (you'd be up to date).

But that is merely the prerequisite to get a merge in the first place.

As for the merge *conflict:* It doesn't have to be the same line of code, it could be an adjacent line. And there are other ways to get a merge conflict, like one side deletes the file entirely.

What matters, however, is not "one of the commits made locally". It is the *totality* of what has been done on each side since the last common commit. If you had a commit that edited the same line he edited, and then you had another commit that changed it back again or changed it to what he has, there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both repos must have at least one unsynchronized commit each that changes the same lines. Otherwise, the most up-to-date change in the remote branch will be transferred to the local clone without a conflict.

Comment: In `git pull --all`, the `--all` has no effect on the merge step. (It has no *useful* effect at all, in general.)

Comment: So, @torek, then are you suggesting that git pull --all simply fetches from each branch and merges the changes just as git pull would do (only in current branch) ?

Comment: @Shreyansh: `git pull --all` passes `--all` to `git fetch`, where it means *fetch from all remotes*. If you have one remote named `origin`, it has no effect. The *second* command that `git pull` runs (merge or rebase) never sees the `--all` and does only the current branch.

Comment: But this is still not accurate, because there might be a commit that changes those lines followed by a commit that changes them back again — and so there is no merge conflict. I think you'll find that my answer gives a more careful statement of the case (though even there I am somewhat hampered by the OP's false assumption that Git commits are themselves about changes).